# ImageView decentralized

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a code to add buttons dynamically in a `RelativeLayout` (MyButton extends of Button and have a `setTag` and `getTag` to set an `ImageView`). The buttons may have a `ImageView` as an icon or not.

Code that assigns the ImageView button (like an icon):
// if user set theme with icons

```
if (this.isShowIcons() == true) {
    if (newButton.getTag() != null) {

        newButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, ((ImageView) newButton.getTag()).getDrawable(), null, null);
        newButton.setPadding(leftpadding, toppadding, rightpadding, bottompadding);
    } else {
        newButton.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    }
} else {
    newButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
    newButton.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
}
```

It turns out that when I inserted the line in the manifest specifying the target and minimal version, the icon appear in bottom position inside button.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

If I simply remove the line `uses-sdk`, works on most devices, but the layout is a problem in **Tablets** for example:

The ImageView sample:

```
ImageView imb1 = new ImageView(this.getBaseContext());
imb1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_1);
imb1.setMaxHeight(120);
imb1.setMaxWidth(120);
imb1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);

MyButton b1 = new MyButton(this);
b1.setText("Label...");
b1.setId(1001);
b1.setTag(imb1);
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I removed the padding in both situations, it worked.